# Uploading File from Vue to Flask CORS Doesn't Work

Tags: flask, cors, flask-cors

I am trying to upload a file from vue to flask, but I get

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows
>   reading the remote resource at http://localhost:5000/upload.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)..

This is my vue code:

```
<script>
  var Vue = require('vue');
  Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    methods: {
      onFileChange(e) {
        var files = e.target.files || e.dataTransfer.files;
        if (!files.length)
          return;
        let data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', files[0]);
        Vue.http.post('http://localhost:5000/upload', this.fileUploadFormData, function (data) {
          alert('good')
        });
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

And this is my app.py

```
import os

from flask import Flask, render_template, app, send_file, request, jsonify, flash, redirect, url_for
from livereload import Server
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from pandas import read_csv
from flask_cors import CORS, cross_origin


app = Flask(__name__)
cors = CORS(app, resorces={r'/*': {"origins": '*'}})
app.config['CORS_HEADER'] = 'Content-Type'


UPLOAD_FOLDER = 'static/uploads'
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='*', headers=['Content-Type', 'Authorization'])
def upload_file():
    return send_file('static/html/index.html')


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
@cross_origin(origin='*', headers=['Content-Type', 'Authorization'])
def uploadFile():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # check if the post request has the file part
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        # if user does not select file, browser also
        # submit a empty part without filename
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('No selected file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file:
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            full_filename = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename)
            file.save(full_filename)
            df = read_csv(full_filename, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)
            return str(df.to_json())
    #return redirect(url_for('upload_file', file=filename))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.debug = True
    server = Server(app.wsgi_app)
    #server.serve()
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

On this line: `cors = CORS(app, resorces={r'/*': {"origins": '*'}})` you have a typo. Change `resorces` to `resources`.

Answer (score 0):

add http
vi du
<FileUpload name="demo[]" url="localhost:8080/upload" @upload="onAdvancedUpload($event)" :multiple="true" :maxFileSize="1000000">
<FileUpload name="demo[]" url="http://localhost:8080/upload" @upload="onAdvancedUpload($event)" :multiple="true" :maxFileSize="1000000">

Comment: Please format your answer properly and explain what your code is doing

Comment: I.e. please use https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and [answer].