# File upload to flask API from Vue JS with fetch API

Tags: vue.js, flask, cors, fetch-api, flask-cors

I have been trying to create an API in flask that allows users to upload an image to the backend server from  a Vue JS SPA front end. The backend API is currently running on localhost:5000 and the frontend SPA on localhost:5173 in dev mode. I have enabled CORS using flask_cors. GET, POST, PUT and DELETE requests are all working as expected using request.json to access data in the http body sent as json. I am trying to make a PUT request with an image file as the http request body using the fetch API as follows:

```
    let file = new FormData();
    let imageFile = document.getElementById("select-image").files[0];
    file.append("file", imageFile, "file");

    fetch('http://localhost:5000/image-file',
      {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Authorization': token
        },
        body: file
      })
      .then(async http => {
        let response = http.text();
        if (http.ok) {
          console.log("created")
        }
        else {
          return response.then(response => {throw new Error(response);})
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
```

This request seems to be working as expected, however I haven't been able find a way to handle it on the backend and access the file. If I ignore the file on the backend, I get no error, i.e, this works fine:

```
@app.route("/image-file", methods=["PUT"])
@user_only
@cross_origin(origin='localhost')
def new_image_file(artist_name):
    return "complete"
```

However, as soon as I try to access the file in any way, it breaks:

```
@app.route("/image-file", methods=["PUT"])
@user_only
@cross_origin(origin='localhost')
def new_image_file(artist_name):
    file = request.files["file"]
    return "complete"
```

In the backend, this throws:

```
werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequestKeyError: 400 Bad Request: The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

In the frontend, it throws a CORS error followed by an internal server error:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5000/image-file' from origin 'http://localhost:5173' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

PUT http://localhost:5000/image-file net::ERR_FAILED 500 (INTERNAL SERVER ERROR)
```

Any thoughts on why this might be? My assumption is that there is something preventing the transfer of files between different origins, but I can't find any info on how to fix that.

FLASK_CORS is set up like this:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```

The solution given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42400108/uploading-file-from-vue-to-flask-cors-doesnt-work) doesn't work.

Comment: You didn't configure `fetch` for cors requests. It doesn't make sense to aim related vue questions because your issue is solely fetch api. It's unknown what's your FE setup. If it's Vue CLI or so (which isn't the same thing as Vue at all) then configure dev server proxy, especially if FE and BE are expected to have the same origin in prod

Comment: @EstusFlask thanks, how would I go about configuring fetch for cors requests? I am using Vite rather than Vue CLI (I believe those to be the same type of thing). FE and BE will not have the same origin in production. Do you know why it would be working for other requests but just not when I try to send a file?

Comment: In this case FE doesn't seem to need changes, but BE needs to explicitly list localhost:5173 or * in Access-Control-Allow-Origin. You should be able to see this header in network request. This is what the link suggested, it's unknown why it doesn't work. I don't use Flask so I can't help with that part